# How to check if datagridview cell with a number

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, datagrid

How i can check if Datagridview have a value...? For example:

```
If DatagridviewRows(i).Cells(2).Value have a value and  
      DatagridviewRows(i).Cells(3).Value Then 
         DatagridviewRows(i).Cells(2).Value = "autosum"
```

I dont want to use If not Datagridview is nothing or string.empty.

Comment: Since datagridview cell value is an object, you have to use the nothing keyword, even if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some variation of the Nothing keyword, as Zohar Peled says in the comment. This is because the cell stores an Object, which is reference type, and Nothing is the correct way to check against reference types.

You don't have to use the format:

```
If Not value Is Nothing Then
```

if it is that format that you dislike. You can instead use:

```
If value IsNot Nothing Then
```

which comes across better from a readability point of view that is more consistent with the English sentence like notation of VB.

Either of those above is the way to do it.